# Webpack doesn't import a node dependency

Tags: typescript, webpack

I'm working on a Three.js project in typescript, but when I transpile it to Javascript the browser can't handle the imports and exports. But digging a little bit more i discovered Webpack, that from my understanding it "translates" de whole code for the browser. It's totally new for me, and I'm struggling on it a little bit.

This is my terminal after running `npx webpack`

```
ERROR in ./src/core.ts 26:25-84
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'three/examples/jsm/postprocessing/EffectComposer' in 'C:\path_to_project\src'
 @ ./src/index.ts 29:31-48

ERROR in ./src/core.ts 27:21-76
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'three/examples/jsm/postprocessing/GlitchPass' in 'C:\path_to_project\src'
 @ ./src/index.ts 29:31-48

ERROR in ./src/core.ts 28:21-76
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'three/examples/jsm/postprocessing/RenderPass' in 'C:\path_to_project\src'
 @ ./src/index.ts 29:31-48

ERROR in ./src/core.ts 29:27-43
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'three' in 'C:\path_to_project\src'
 @ ./src/index.ts 29:31-48

ERROR in ./src/geometries.ts 27:27-43
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'three' in 'C:\path_to_project\src'
 @ ./src/index.ts 30:30-53

5 errors have detailed information that is not shown.
Use 'stats.errorDetails: true' resp. '--stats-error-details' to show it.

webpack 5.75.0 compiled with 5 errors in 6524 ms
```

It's trying to find the ***three/examples/...*** files at my main ***/src/*** folder, but all the "three" stuff are files from the node_modules dependency.

The first lines of `src/core.ts` shows the imports that webpack is messing up:

```js
import { EffectComposer } from 'three/examples/jsm/postprocessing/EffectComposer';
import { GlitchPass } from 'three/examples/jsm/postprocessing/GlitchPass';
import { RenderPass } from 'three/examples/jsm/postprocessing/RenderPass';
import * as THREE from "three";
```

And as you can see, they are files that are not in my /src/, are at node_modules. Their whole path is: `C:/path_to_project/node_modules/@types/three/examples/jsm/postprocessing/`

I really don't know how to fix it or how to tell webpack that they are npm dependencies for import. I've been looking for help it's been some time but still nothing...

If this helps, my `webpack.config.js` file looks like this:

```js
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    entry: './src/index.ts',
    mode: 'development',
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.tsx?$/,
                use: 'ts-loader',
                exclude: /node_modules/
            },
        ],
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.tsx', '.ts', '.js'],
        modules: ['node_modules'],
    },
    output: {
        filename: 'app.js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'public', 'dist'),
    },
};
```

Comment: `node_modules/@types` only contains typescript type bindings, no actual module code. Are you sure you have installed three (`npm i three`)?

Comment: @MoritzRingler oooh, i thought even the `@types` files were transpiled to js, now i added three and it worth. Thanks a lot man